# Remove a series in Graphite when using postgres for storage?

Tags: postgresql, graphite

Just installed graphite using postgres for storage and sending data to graphite using statsd. Works fine!

My issue is I created a bunch of series (mostly gauges) that were just for testing and I want them gone but see no way to delete them. I have no whisper files to delete since I am using postgres.

In looking at the tables in postgres for the graphite database I see nothing that contains the series. I see my custom graphs and my user but nowhere in the graphite database can I find my testing series to blow away.

Any pointers? Are the series not kept in the postgres DB?

Answer (score 0):

Graphite only uses PostgreSQL/MySQL/SQLite for storing user profiles, saved graphs & dashboards, and events (annotation-style data). Time-series metrics are stored in the native Whisper files. In most cases these files will exist under `/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/`.

Say you sent a metric by accident named `foo.bar.baz`. This file will exist at `/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/foo/bar/baz.wsp` and can be deleted from the command-line with `sudo rm /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/foo/bar/baz.wsp`.

Comment: I see nothing in /opt which is why I initially opened this question :)  # ls -al /opt
    total 8
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 16 03:54 .
    drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 Aug 24 23:49 ..

Could graphite be storing this data in another location?